# SVG in HTML: Inline vs. embed

Tags: html, svg, embed

When I embed a set of SVG graphics elements inline into HTML I have access to e.g. a group, say a chesspiece, via its id-attribute and can make it clickable, draggable  and so on. Very nice and straight forward.

Now I remove the SVG code from the HTML and put it into a separate file which I include via

```
<embed src=... />
```

into the HTML. This works with no apparent difference in the rendering, but now I don't have access to the group via its id-attribute any more. With

```
<object data=...></object>
```

it is the same, by the way.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your script in the html file, you want something like this...

document.getElementById("embed_or_object_id").getSVGDocument().getElementById("element_id");

Comment: I tried your approach and noticed that the problem starts with the click event handler: <embed id="svg" src=... /> together with  $("#svg").click(function(e) {alert("click noticed");}); does nothing. How can I make an <embed>-element sensitive to clicks?

Comment: That's not possible. Clicks go to the content. You could either put a transparent absolutely positioned div on top and handle the clicks there or handle the clicks in the content svg.